# why std::unique_ptr vector gets invalid pointer exception

Tags: c++11, vector, runtime-error, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I wrote simple code to help me understand smart pointers:

```
string s = "str";
vector <unique_ptr<string>> pv ;

pv.push_back(unique_ptr<string>(&s));
cout<<*(pv[0])<<endl;
```

This code compiles fine, but gets me a runtime error:

> str
>   *** Error in `...': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffd956e57e0 *** Aborted (core dumped)

What happened and what have I done wrong?

Comment: A `unique_ptr` to something on the stack makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

In the `std::unique_ptr`'s destructor it will call `delete` on the `&s` pointer which was not allocated via `new`.

Just use:

```
std::vector<std::string> vector;
vector.emplace_back("str");
std::cout << pv[0] << std::endl;
```

There's no need for `std::unique_ptr<std::string>` there.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is being destructed twice - once when your `pv` goes out of scope and is deleted, freeing all its contained `unique_ptr` elements, and once when `s` goes out of scope.

To use a vector of unique pointers (or to use unique pointers in general), it is essential that they are not aliased. So you could write:

```
auto *s = new std::string("str");
pv.push_back(std::unique_ptr<std::string>(s));
// do not write "delete s" anywhere...
```

Or, simpler and safer:

```
pv.push_back(std::make_unique<std::string>("str")); // make_unique is C++14
```

Or even:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::string> p{new std::string("str")};
pv.push_back(std::move(p));
// Do not attempt to use p beyond this point.
```