# C++ unique_ptr initialization through constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, unique-ptr

I have simple (I suppose) problem with my C++ code. Each time I initialize unique_ptr through constructor I'm getting the same problem:

> **munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffc40ba6bf0**

Here's the code:

1) Private part of the class:

```
template<typename T>
class Node{
  typedef std::unique_ptr<Node> ptr;
  T value;
  ptr left, right;
```

2) Constructor initializing ptr left and ptr right:

```
explicit Node(const T value, Node* left = nullptr, Node* right = nullptr):
  value{value}, left{left}, right{right} {}
```

What is the problem here? Thanks for clarification or pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: should probably be `explicit Node(const T value, ptr left = nullptr, ptr right = nullptr): value{value}, left{std::move(left)}, right{std::move(right)} {}`.

Comment: There is no problem in this code, although passing in raw pointers is not ideal. The actual problem must be somewhere else; I suspect you're double-freeing those pointers.

Comment: @Jarod42 `move` does nothing for raw pointers.

Comment: I agree with @SebastianRedl, use Valgrind to check for memory handling issues if you cannot find the source of the bug.

Comment: Maybe left and right are the same address in your crash-case?

Comment: Try to accept unique_ptr's instead of pointers so the caller is responsible by their uniqueness.

Comment: Maybe related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357344/why-stdunique-ptr-vector-gets-invalid-pointer-exception)?

Comment: @SebastianRedl you misread Jarod42's change. `ptr` is an alias for `std::unique_ptr`, so he's hoisted the exposure of unique_ptr, hence the std::move.

Comment: I would suppose the caller retains ownership of the pointers and deletes them at some point.

Comment: @YamMarcovic, now his is not. Read the code.

Comment: @YamMarcovic `Node(const T value, ptr left = nullptr, ptr right = nullptr` <-- he's changed the arguments from raw to std::unique_ptr (`typedef std::unique_ptr ptr`), *then* `value{value}, left{std::move(left)}, right{std::move(right)} {}`

Comment: @YamMarcovic, so was I. I urge you to read the code :) Jarod could be more explicit, though.

Comment: @kfsone,SergeyA Oh, now I see it. :)

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, it could do obviously but I want the type to be Node* (for user convenience). Example initizalization: Node<int> node(12);
  Node<int> node2(15, &node);

Comment: @xxxxx, here you go. Here is your problem right here!!! You are using unique_ptr to hold an address of automatic varaible!

Comment: @xxxx Perhaps that's your problem. You're destroying twice now.

Comment: @xxxxx: And my change would catch this error :-) In your case, the member should not be `unique_ptr`.

Comment: What's the good close reason here?

Comment: @Jarod42 Would it? He'd still be passing in a pointer which unique_ptr should accept. Isn't that the case?

Comment: @YamMarcovic: With my change, the ownership transfer is obvious, and at the call site we may see the error. Here, we need to see call site + class definition.

Comment: @YamMarcovic, That constructor is explicit. One would need to do `Node<int> node2(15, std::make_unique(&node))`, something that should ring alarm bells and that static analysis tools can easily look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment *Example initizalization:*

```
Node<int> node(12);
Node<int> node2(15, &node);
```

will obviously crash, since you pass the address of an automatic variable (`node`) into a `unique_ptr<>`, which upon its destruction will try to `delete` it, even though it was never allocated with `new`.

Use `unique_ptr<>` only for objects on the heap!*

(Another lesson from this exercise: always put a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is guaranteed to contain the problem, while your code didn't.)

<sub>* unless you know what you're doing, i.e. if `delete` is overloaded for your type or if you pass an appropriate deleter to `unique_ptr`.</sub>

Comment: `unique_ptr` isn't just for heap objects. By default it uses the `delete` keyword which can also be overridden for certain types; also, it can use a custom deleter.

Comment: @YamMarcovic Yes, you can do all that, but that's more advanced than this user. I will change my answer to mention this.

Comment: Thank you for tips, will definitely remember those, appreciated and sorry for duplicate.